# Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged (with SWRevealViewController)

Tags: swift3, swrevealviewcontroller, side-menu

I am changing the RootViewController of SwRevealViewController

My code:

```
let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SWRevealViewController") as! SWRevealViewController
    next.loadView()
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MessageViewController") as! MessageViewController
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = viewController;

    self.present(next, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But I get this error:

```
>Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged <ios.MesajDetayViewController: 0x7f8718d646f0>.
```

How to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> solution

```
    let sw = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SWRevealViewController") as! SWRevealViewController
self.view.window?.rootViewController = sw

let mainStroyBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let desController = mainStroyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MessageViewController") as! MessageViewController
let newFrontViewController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController:desController)
sw.pushFrontViewController(newFrontViewController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change `SWRevealViewContoller` front view controller, you should use

```
let newFronViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourID") as! YourClass
self.revealViewController().setFront(newFronViewController, animated: false)
```

I can update my answer depending on where you would like to call this.